# Can I replace rich text - pm with p&zwnj;m

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We want to make every time a user inputs 8pm or 9am in a text field in content editor, when the email is sent the pm and am are broken up with a zero-width-non-joiner. e.g `8p&zwnj;m`

Is that possible with `replace()`?

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet?

Comment: I don't have a code snippet - I was hoping to find a general way of replacing all instances of pm with 8`&zwnj;`pm within a content module.

Comment: Do you mean directly inside of the Email Studio?

Comment: Yes directly in the email studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFMC does not allow you to change anything in the default UI that would allow this.  Your best bet would be one of two options:

1. To have your content inserted elsewhere and then pull in that content via AMPScript/SSJS or API and do your replace there. Example via external Content block, API retrieve or Data Extension.
2. To build your own content block with custom settings via [Content Block SDK](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/content-builder-block-sdk/build-a-custom-block) to handle this and any other custom rules you may have.